# css how can i center multiple elements with absolute position

Tags: css

How do i group all the elements which have absolute position and center all of them together inside a parent div? i also will be adding and removing each element using jquery and want them to be centered automatically. 
So in my jsfiddle example, i want to group all three cards and center them together. Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/ksha09jk/2/

html

```
<div class='wrap'>
  <li class='card card1'>Q</li>
  <li class='card card2'>K</li>
  <li class='card card3'>A</li>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrap{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
.card{
  width: 43px;
  height: 60px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}
.card1{
  position: absolute;
  top:15px;
  left: 0px;
}
.card2{
  position: absolute;
  top:15px;
  left: 30px;
}
.card3{
  position: absolute;
  top:15px;
  left: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block` property with `text-align: center` on parent to centralizer your cards.

```css
.wrap {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 0 0;
  height: 100px;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.content li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 60px;
  width: 43px;
}
```

```html
 <div class='wrap'>
   <ul class="content">
     <li>Q</li>
     <li>K</li>
     <li>A</li>
     <li>K</li>
     <li>A</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: is there a way to do it with absolute position attached for each card? i didn't realize that u have removed it on your version. i was looking to do some positioning animation with each individual card when its clicked.

Comment: @lys916 you can try animation on `margin-left` property. Might be it solve your problem.

Comment: @lys916 And if `margin-left` not solve your problem, I think you need to assign hard-coded `width` and `height` on `.content` by calculating the number of items inside it to make it in center.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it works for you

https://jsfiddle.net/GirdhariAgrawal/ksha09jk/3/

**CSS Code**

```
.wrap{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
.card{
  width: 43px;
  height: 60px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;

}
.card1{
  position: absolute;
  top:15px;
  left: 0px;
}
.card2{
  position: absolute;
  top:15px;
  left: 30px;
}
.card3{
  position: absolute;
  top:15px;
  left: 60px;

}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50% !important;
}
```

Comment: this is close, but how do i make it center from the middle of the cards? if i add two more cards then it'll just shift to the right. like this... https://jsfiddle.net/ksha09jk/4/

Comment: Please is mine buddy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it will help.

```css
.wrap{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  left:50%
}
.card{
  width: 43px;
  height: 60px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}
.card1{
  position: absolute;
  
  top:15px;
  left: 0px;
}
.card2{
  position: absolute;
  top:15px;
  left: 30px;
}
.card3{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top:15px;
  left: 60px;
}
.group{
 background-color: green;
 left:0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='group'>
     <div class='wrap'>
      <li class='card card1'>Q</li>
      <li class='card card2'>K</li>
      <li class='card card3'>A</li>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: im trying to center all the cards.. not the letters. sorry if i didn't make it clear in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `align` attribute to the `div` with the `center` value like this `<div class="wrap" align="center">`

Comment: i was trying to center the cards.. not the letters. sorry if i didn't make it clear.

Comment: Yes, my answer will center the cards

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrap{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}
.wrap>li{
 display: inline-block;
 height: 60px;
 width: 43px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin-right: -2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <li>Q</li>
  <li>K</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>J</li>
</div>
```

You can try the above code, Hope it will works...!

Comment: i wanted the effect of cards stacking on top of one another, the reason i use absolute position for each card. this removes that effect.